# In c socket, why my server can't receive the whole content?

Tags: c, sockets

I am new in this field, and writing one server and client, but it really confusing that I can't get all the content, but some small clip. 
My server code:

```
        read(connfd, name, 20);
        //recv(connfd,name,1024,0);
        char* a=name;
        while(a[0]!='\n'){
            a++;
        }
        a[0]='\0';
        printf("name:%s\n", name);
        read(connfd, size, 20);
        printf("size:%s\n", size);
        recv(connfd,buf,8192,0);
        printf("buf:%s\n", buf);
        if((stream = fopen(name,"w+t"))==NULL){
            printf("The file was not opened! \n");
        }
        int write_length = fwrite(buf,sizeof(char),8192,stream);
        bzero(buf,8192);
        if(put){
        char *res="OK\n";
        write(connfd, res, 1024);
        }
        fclose(stream);
```

and my client code is:

```
char buffer[8192];
bzero(buffer,8192);
char * put="PUT\n";
if ((write(fd, put, 8192)) <= 0) {
    if (errno != EINTR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Write error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
    }
}
struct stat st ;
stat( put_name, &st );
char str[100];
sprintf(str, "%d", st.st_size);
int len;
char *current=NULL;
len=strlen(put_name);   

char sendname[1024];
strcpy(sendname,put_name);
strcat(sendname,"\n");
write(fd, sendname, 10);
strcat(str,"\n");
write(fd, str, 10);
FILE *stream;
if((stream = fopen(put_name,"r"))==NULL)
{
    printf("The file was not opened! \n");
    exit(1);
}
int lengsize = 0;
while((lengsize = fread(buffer,1,8192,stream)) > 0){
    if(send(fd,buffer,8192,0)<0){
        printf("Send File is Failed\n");
        break;
    }
    bzero(buffer, 8192);
}
```

Now, I can send all content, but can receive part of them. for example, on my mac, server can receive name but the `str` is neglected, when I printf the str in the server, it shows the content of file. and the content of file is not the whole file content. Some content disappear. Could you tell me why?

Comment: `read` and `recv` aren't guaranteed to return as many bytes as requested. You gotta check their return values, and keep reading until you've found the end of what you want to read. Similarly, `write` (and `send`?) might not send as many bytes as requested. You gotta check its return value and call it in a loop.

Comment: could you give some example? appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the return values of `send()` and `recv()`.  You MUST check return values!

When sending the file, `lengsize` receives how many bytes were actually read from the file.  Your client is sending too many bytes when `lengsize` is < 8192 (typically the last block of the file if the file size is not an even multiple of 8192).

But more importantly, although the client is telling the server the file size, the server is ignoring it to know when to stop reading.  The server is also ignoring the return value of `recv()` to know how many bytes were actually received so it knows how many bytes can safely be written to the output file.

Try something more like this instead:

common:

```
int readData(int s, void *buf, int buflen)
{
    int total = 0;
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    while (buflen > 0) {
        int numread = recv(s, pbuf, buflen, 0);
        if (numread <= 0) return numread;
        pbuf += numread;
        buflen -= numread;
        total += numread;
    }
    return total;
}

int sendData(int s, void *buf, int buflen)
{
    int total = 0;
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    while (buflen > 0) {
        int numsent = send(s, pbuf, buflen, 0);
        if (numsent <= 0) return numsent;
        pbuf += numsent;
        buflen -= numsent;
        total += numsent;
    }
    return total;
}

int readInt32(int s, int32_t *value)
{
    int res = readData(s, value, sizeof(*value));
    if (res > 0) *value = ntohl(*value);
    return res;
}

int sendInt32(int s, int32_t value)
{
    value = htonl(value);
    return sendData(s, &value, sizeof(value));
}

char* readStr(int s)
{
    int32_t size;
    if (readInt32(s, &size) <= 0)
        return NULL;

    char *str = malloc(size+1);
    if (!str)
         return NULL;

    if (readData(s, str, size) <= 0) {
        free(str);
        return NULL;
    }
    str[size] = '\0';

    return str;
}

int sendStr(int s, const char *str)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    int res = sendInt32(s, len);
    if (res > 0)
        res = sendData(s, str, len);
    return res;
}
```

server:

```
char buffer[8192];

char *name = readStr(connfd);
if (!name) {
    // error handling ...
    sendStr(connfd, "Socket read error");
    return;
}
printf("name:%s\n", name);

int32_t filesize;
if (readInt32(connfd, &filesize) <= 0) {
    // error handling ...
    free(name);
    sendStr(connfd, "Socket read error");
    return;
}
printf("size:%d\n", filesize);

if ((stream = fopen(name, "wb")) == NULL) {
    // error handling ...
    printf("The file was not opened!\n");
    free(name);
    sendStr(connfd, "File not opened");
    return;
}

while (filesize > 0) {
    int numread = readData(connfd, buf, min(filesize, sizeof(buffer)));
    if (numread <= 0) {
        // error handling ...
        close(stream);
        free(name);
        sendStr(connfd, "Socket read error");
        return;
    }

    printf("buf:%.*s\n", numread, buf);

    if (fwrite(buf, 1, numread, stream) != numread) {
        // error handling ...
        close(stream);
        free(name);
        sendStr(connfd, "File write error");
        return;
    }

    filesize -= numread;
}

fclose(stream);
free(name);

sendStr(connfd, "OK");
```

client:

```
char buffer[8192];

struct stat st;
if (stat( put_name, &st ) != 0) {
    // error handling ...
    exit(0);
}

if ((stream = fopen(put_name, "rb")) == NULL) {
    // error handling ...
    printf("The file was not opened!\n");
    exit(0);
}

if (sendStr(fd, put_name) <= 0) {
    // error handling ...
    close(stream);
    exit(0);
}

int32_t filesize = st.st_size;
if (sendInt32(fd, filesize) <= 0) {
    // error handling ...
    close(stream);
    exit(0);
}

int lengsize;
while (filesize > 0) {
    lengsize = fread(buffer, 1, min(filesize , sizeof(buffer)), stream);
    if (lengsize <= 0) {
        printf("Read File Failed\n");
        // error handling ...
        close(stream);
        exit(0);
    }

    if (sendData(fd, buffer, lengsize) <= 0) {
        printf("Send File Failed\n");
        // error handling ...
        close(stream);
        exit(0);
    }

    filesize -= lengsize;
}

close(stream);

char *resp = readStr(fd);
if (!resp) {
    // error handling ...
    exit(0);
}

if (strcmp(resp, "OK") == 0)
    printf("Send File OK\n");
else
    printf("Send File Failed: %s\n", resp);

free(resp);
```

Comment: TCP is a byte stream. You can send whatever you want, as long as you read it in the same order that it is sent. TCP may transmit multiple items together on the wire, but your code should not rely on that. In my example, the client sends a 32-bit filename size, then the filename characters, then a 32-bit file size, then the file data. The server reads the 32-bit filename length, then the filename characters, then the 32-bit file size, then the file data. If you need to handle files > 2GB in size, use a 64-bit file size instead.

Comment: you are so helpful!

Answer (score 4):

The `read` and `write` functions are not guaranteed to send or receive the entire message with a single call. Instead, you're expected to sit in a loop, writing the message incrementally until everything has been sent and reading everything incrementally until everything has been read. For example, if you know *exactly* how much has been sent, you can do this:

```
char recvBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int  bytesRead = 0;

while (bytesRead < BUFFER_SIZE) {
    int readThisTime = read(file, recvBuffer + bytesRead, BUFFER_SIZE - bytesRead);
    if (readThisTime == -1) {
       // handle error...
    }
    bytesRead += readThisTime;
}
```

If you don't know exactly how much has been sent, try this:

```
char recvBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int  bytesRead = 0;

while (bytesRead < BUFFER_SIZE) {
    int readThisTime = read(file, recvBuffer + bytesRead, BUFFER_SIZE - bytesRead);
    if (readThisTime == -1) {
       // handle error...
    }
    if (readThisTime == 0) break; // Done!

    bytesRead += readThisTime;
}
```

Comment: It used to be that FTP clients would lose the end of files. I think it happened when the FIN packet arrived before the final data packet. As such, I think it's important to check that you received everything you should have received. That means the second snippet requires an additional check (e.g. the sender must provide the length of the message or a sentinel, and the receiver must check the length or for the sentinel)

Comment: @ikegami Certainly that would be a good idea in a more structured setting. The example here was mostly to show how to use read in a loop. If there were other constraints on the type or shape of the data that was being sent around, you'd definitely need to update this!